# How to count player scores on Local Host and Client

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

Hello I'm currently making a game at the moment that's like pacman but multiplayer. I'm having trouble on how to network the scores. I'm wanting to show own score on Local host and own score on Client. So far I could only update scores for the Local Host. Could anyone please help?

Score Manager:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class ScoreManager : NetworkBehaviour {


public static int score;        


Text text;                     


void Start()
{

    text = GetComponent<Text>();


    score = 0;
}


void Update()
{
    if (!isServer)
    {
        return;
    }

    text.text = "Score: " + score;
}
}
```

Ontriggerstart for score

```
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;
 using UnityEngine.UI;




public class PacDot : MonoBehaviour {




void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D co)
{

    if (co.tag == "UFO")
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
        ScoreManager.score++;
    }

}



}
```

Player Code:

```
using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;
 using UnityEngine.Networking;


 public class UFOMove : NetworkBehaviour {

public float speed;


private Rigidbody2D rb2d;  



void Start()
{
    rb2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (!isLocalPlayer)
    {
        return;
    }

    float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");       
    float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");      
    Vector2 movement = new Vector2(moveHorizontal, moveVertical);       
    rb2d.AddForce(movement * speed);
}

}
```

Comment: Are you talking about local multiplayer (on the same machine) or online multiplayer?

Comment: @Rawpnzel on local